# Increase bing map control map area size on Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, bing-maps

I have a bing maps control in my WP app, but it only covers like half the screen, how can I set it to fit the entire screen? setting the height doesn't work.

There really isn't much to share, here is my code :

```
 xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"  


<my:Map ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed" x:Name="map" Height="490">
```

however changing the height over "490", increases the map area, but not the map itself, so anything beyong 490 is only black and not map

Comment: please share your codes..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are developing for WP7. WP7 uses Bing Maps (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps). WP8 uses a different map control (Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls).

In any case, put your map inside of a Grid. The map will stretch to fill the grid. Remove the height value unless to you want to limit the height of the map.